# Optimal way for keeping an observable state in Rx

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive

I've got a question about what would be the better RxJava pattern in order to keep an observable state.

To keep it simple, let's assume we have a `StateManager` class that needs to keep track of a certain state (let's assume it's a simple boolean flag) in the system and expose it in an observable way. As such, it would have a method such as below:

```
class StateManager {
    Observable<Boolean> state();
    ...
}
```

This manager has a very long lifecycle and could have multiple "clients" (e.g. views, other managers etc.) that would subscribe or unsubscribe at any time. The state would be changed based on some internal events.

The most obvious way to deal with this would be to hold the state in a `BehaviourSubject` to which consumers hook directly:

```
class StateManager {

    Subject mStateSubject = BehaviourSubject.create(true);        

    Observable<Boolean> state() {
        return mStateSubject.asObservable();
    }    
    ...
}
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subjects` are probably the least desirable way to use reactive libraries, though it can certainly work.

Functional-reactive programming works best without state. `Subjects` are a form of state. I recommend changing your code so that the Observable is defined as a combination of functional operators. This makes it easy to test and manage the messages your observable is emitting.

---

I'm more of a C# developer, so I hope you'll excuse the different syntax. Here's an example:

```
void Main()
{
    var tracker = new AddTracker();
    tracker.getSums().Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(t => t.Timestamp.Second)
        .Take(20)
        .Subscribe(i => tracker.setA(i % 7));

    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(75))
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(t => t.Timestamp.Millisecond)
        .Take(30)
        .Subscribe(i => tracker.setB(i % 9));

}

public class AddTracker
{
    private readonly ISubject<int> _a;
    private readonly ISubject<int> _b;
    private readonly IObservable<int> _sums;
    private readonly IDisposable _dummySub;

    public AddTracker()
    {
        _a = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
        _b = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
        _sums = _a
            .CombineLatest(_b, (a, b) => a + b)
            .Replay(1)
            .RefCount();
        _dummySub = _sums.Subscribe(_ => { });
    }

    public void setA(int value)
    {
        _a.OnNext(value);
    }

    public void setB(int value)
    {
        _b.OnNext(value);
    }

    public IObservable<int> getSums()
    {
        return _sums;
    }
}
```

In C# land, you could swap out the `_a` and `_b` subjects for events, which is a mild improvement. I know there's no first-class events in Java, so I'm not sure that would translate.

More fundamentally however, in both C# and Java, the question you should ask is...what's causing the `setA` and `setB` calls? And could you replace them with this:

```
void Main()
{
    var aStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(t => t.Timestamp.Second)
        .Take(20);

    var bStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(75))
        .Timestamp()
        .Select(t => t.Timestamp.Millisecond)
        .Take(30);

    var tracker = new AddTracker(aStream, bStream);
    tracker.getSums().Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

}

public class AddTracker
{
    private readonly IObservable<int> _sums;
    private readonly IDisposable _dummySub;

    public AddTracker(IObservable<int> a, IObservable<int> b)
    {
        _sums = a
            .CombineLatest(b, (aItem, bItem) => (aItem % 9) + (bItem % 7))
            .Replay(1)
            .RefCount();
        _dummySub = _sums.Subscribe(_ => {});
    }

    public IObservable<int> getSums()
    {
        return _sums;
    }
}
```

In short, if you must, start with subjects. Then take your subjects, and keep pushing them as far away from your logic as possible.

Comment: Yes, these are very good points. However, in my case, I *do* need to keep a state and expose changes to the consumers, if any. Do you have a more concrete example of "a combination of functional operators" applicable for my case?

Comment: Added a somewhat contrived example.

Answer (score 1):

The described case is what it calls 'Hot' observable - observable that its producer (emissions source) created outside of subscription,
(as described by Ben Lesh at [Hot vs Cold Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339#.9fbl19mgd) - recommended reading).

as Shlomo said, Subjects are the "mutable variables" of Rx world, and you can get along with creating a 'cold' observable by using Obsevable.create (which listen to the events and produce the emissions based on them), and then make it 'hot' using operators that transform it to ConnectableObservable (like share, publish), in order for multicast it to multiple observers that subscribe at different times.

But, in this case as the producer is local to your class (events are generated by this class) it is the case where it is OK to use Subject for this purpose, as your class itself is the source of emissions and the mutual/state variable that produce the events.
(based on [answer given by Erik Meijer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbf87eea-6a17-4920-96d7-2131e397a234/why-does-emeijer-not-like-subjects), and this [blog post](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx))